# Will the full or subset of the .NET framework be eventually ported/re-engineered to work with ARM instruction set?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

As per the information released by Microsoft in
recent days it is clear that the .NET framework has indeed
NOT been ported to ARM, hence even applications
that make use purely of .NET libraries (Not WIN32) will in fact
not work on WOA (Windows 8 on ARM), the reason cited is
that the .NET framework (Not sure which parts exactly) is not code/function
compatible with ARM architecture and hence was not ported.

This is sad to hear considering that .NET framework and respective runtime really
act as a virtual machine and managed code written with the use of this framework
should be capable of being OS and also processor/architecture independent provided the 
framework/vm is ported and installed. That's the whole power behind managed code in the
first place, proprietary or not guess Microsoft's promises of a multi-platform capable managed code backing framework that is .NET were a gimmick.

I just hope that this isn't the case and the .NET framework or subset of it can be ported and it's just not a priority at the moment since they can always release it as a download/update. Would sure be nice to run all those .NET desktop apps on the WOA desktop.

Source
http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/windows_on_arm_yes_theres_a_desktop_no_its_not_com.php

Comment: I would think it is highly unlikely the full .NET framework would be ported in the short term. I think they are focusing on using ARM for tablets in the short/medium term so unless you want to use your tablet as a web server a lot of functionality is not required.

Comment: The article is plainly incorrect. Generally speaking, you should not trust any third party source of information that engages in speculation. .NET/XAML remains a supported platform for Metro apps on ARM, alongside C++/XAML and HTML5/JS. Nothing in the original blog post by Sinofsky (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/02/09/building-windows-for-the-arm-processor-architecture.aspx) states otherwise.

Comment: ... also, .NET, in some shape or another, has been running on ARM for a long time now - what, exactly, do you think all those WP7 phones run?

Comment: @Pavel Yes, I know about WinPhones light .NET\Silverlight framework and the upcoming WinRT-Metro library working with which should be near identical as using the .NET library, then again it's not the .NET framework and I would presume not all libraries\classes are present in order to simply port existing .NET desktops apps to use their respective WinRT library counterparts and run on ARM tablet/pc desktop. And are you really sure about this: ".NET/XAML remains a supported platform for Metro apps on ARM", you can use the .NET on x86 Win8 but on ARM I would think it's only metro part of WinRT.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure about that. It's right there in the blog post, in fact: "Metro style apps in the Windows Store can support both WOA and Windows 8 on x86/64. Developers wishing to target WOA do so by writing applications for the WinRT (Windows APIs for building Metro style apps) using the new Visual Studio 11 tools in a variety of languages, including **C#/VB/XAML** and Jscript/HTML5. Native code targeting WinRT is also supported using C and C++, which can be targeted across architectures and distributed through the Windows Store."

Comment: And yes, this is not the full desktop .NET, so you'll need to do some porting. You can run Win8 Dev Preview today to see what is and is not available.

Comment: @Pavel So lets not call it .NET then I guess. Because the full .NET is present in Windows 8 X86/64.

Comment: @LaserBeak Why not call it .NET? There was never any claim that only a complete set of classes that you see on x86 desktop today is .NET. Indeed, for a long time now, the version of CLR that ran on Windows Mobile was called ".NET CE" (Compact Edition), and it had a different standard class library. The version that is used for Win8 Metro is called ".NET Core Framework". But it's still most definitely .NET. In fact, all desktop CLR features are in place, the only difference is in the class library.